# Jersey to json, returning instances that extends a super type

Tags: java, json, tomcat, jersey

I'm having the following issue, I'm creating a web application which uses jersey and I want to return a list of objects as json. These objects are different classes which all extend from a class Bet. I don't get the fields back however that I created in subclasses of Bet.

For example:

```
class Bet {
    String string;
}

class A extends Bet {
    int i;
}
```

When I return a list of Bet containing some objects of A, the json only contains the String in Bet and doesn't show the Integer from class A.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Jackson. Annotate your list property with JsonTypeInfo - this will cause extra type info to be included in your JSON, which in turn allows for proper deserialization when you get the data back:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.CLASS, include=As.PROPERTY, property="class")
private List<Bet> bets;
```